# How do I print the text of a div using bs4

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) and I'm trying to get the names of coins that are at the bottom of the main page.
With this line `crypto_name = crypto_details.find("p", class_="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT")`
It prints me `[<p class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT" color="text" font-size="1" font-weight="semibold">Bitcoin</p>]` which is what I want.
But when I do `print(crypto_name.string.strip())` to only have the name of the coin I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

I tried with .get_text and .string also but got the same result. I also tried replacing find() with find_all() but that obviously doesn't work since there's only one p. I also tried removing the first and last char of the name to get rid of the [ ] but that doesn't solve the problem either.
How do I get it to show the name of the coin and why do I get such an error?

The page is loaded properly (I used selenium to do so)

Full code :

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options
)
driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("div", class_="grid")
crypto_detail = results.find_all("tr")
for crypto_details in crypto_detail:
    crypto_name = crypto_details.find("p", class_="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT")
    print(crypto_name.text.strip())
    sleep(randint(2, 10))
```

Comment: _I used selenium to do so_: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120422/how-to-scrape-historic-snapshot-table-from-coinmarketcap-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: @Curiouskoala yes same error

Answer (score 0):

Hey I managed to get the text back by only using text here is what I did

```
crypto_detail = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT'})
#grabs all the paragraph tags that has the class your looking for
for crypto_details in crypto_detail:
    name = crypto_details.text.strip()
    print(name)
```